# why can I use gradlew on windows?

Tags: gradle, gradle-wrapper

I'm on Windows 10.
I thought that only the `gradlew.bat` script can be run from the terminal/command prompt,  And  `gradlew` only on linux/mac terminal.

I was wondering why I can still run `gradlew` from windows terminal/command prompt ?

Comment: Maybe bash from git app is being used?